# How to determine the revision for a specific android.jar file

Tags: android, android-source

How can the revision of an `android.jar` file be determined.
E.g., given `android-sdk/platforms/android-8/android.jar`,
I would like to retrieve the source code for its contents by deriving its revision and provide it as `-b` option argument to the `repo init` command (acc. to http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html)
Actually, this question could be rephrased:
"*How can I retrieve the source code for a specific `android.jar`?*"
Is there any alternative to using `repo`? I'm only interested in the the Java source-files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for you to use *repo* and gather sources of *android.jar*, since someone else already did it. There are plenty of sites on the web with packaged source for `android.jar` files. Personally I prefer source packages from [adt-addons project](http://code.google.com/p/adt-addons/):

> **Android Sources**
>
> This plugin helps you to add source to android libraries in Eclipse.
>
> In ADT >=8.0.0 you can add Android sources to Android container for
>   all your project with installing the Android source feature using
>   http://adt-addons.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/source/com.android.ide.eclipse.source.update/
>   update site After installing the Android source feature all your
>   existing projects as well as new created projects which is targeted
>   for Android 2.3.4, 2.3, 2.2, 2.1, 2.0.1, 1.6 and 1.5 will have
>   attached the source jar.
>
> The plugin includes sources for the following API levels:
>
> - 10 - Android 2.3.4
> - 9 - Android 2.3
> - 8 - Android 2.2
> - 7 - Android 2.1
> - 6 - Android 2.0.1
> - 4 - Android 1.6
> - 3 - Android 1.5
>
> The plugin is about 170 MB size.